# How to receive daily summary email from firebase analytics?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

I would like to receive daily summary reports by e-mail about my app's downloads and other various stats from **Firebase**. I have used **Fabric** earlier and was able to do so but now since Fabric is going to be deprecated soon (May 2020) - I would like to do the same in Firebase.

Snippet of the e-mail

[image: Fabric e-mail example]

Is there any solution?

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this? I also loved Fabric's daily emails and I can't figure out how to do it for Firebase Analytics

Comment: Is there a workaround, e.g. API or plugin, that anyone used instead?

Answer (score 4):

According to a [Twitter reaction](https://twitter.com/fabric/status/1255189673749741569) to this question:

> It's something we are looking into actively right now. The team is deeply interested in launching something, but can't provide a timeline quite yet.

So as of now (**April 28, 2020**), it is not possible yet. Time will tell.

Comment: Any update on this one? I'm also looking to enable this, I haven't found anything to this date... :(

Comment: anything new? Can not find something